How do I configure the function r2_score from SciKit-Learn to recognize that I have installed PyTorch that uses GPU?
I am new to PyTorch, and I have just installed it and run a somewhat Hello-World example.
First of all, I installed PyTorch as follows.
$ pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118

I also installed SciKit-Learn because it is used inside the Hello-World example.
$ pip3 install scikit-learn

Then, I run the following program.
import torch
from torch import nn
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score


class MyMachine(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2,5),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(5,1)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x


def get_dataset():
        X = torch.rand((1000,2))
        x1 = X[:,0]
        x2 = X[:,1]
        y = x1 * x2
        return X, y


def train():
    model = MyMachine()
    model.train()
    X, y = get_dataset()
    NUM_EPOCHS = 1000
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-2, weight_decay=1e-5)
    criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')

    for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        y_pred = model(X)
        y_pred = y_pred.reshape(1000)
        loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print(f'Epoch:{epoch}, Loss:{loss.item()}')
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model.h5')


def test():
    model = MyMachine()
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load("model.h5"))
    model.eval()
    X, y = get_dataset()

    with torch.no_grad():
        y_pred = model(X)
        print(r2_score(y, y_pred))


train()
test()

After that, I get the following error.
/home/mylab/Workspace/PyTorchScripts/helloworld.py:49: FutureWarning: You are using `torch.load` with `weights_only=False` (the current default value), which uses the default pickle module implicitly. It is possible to construct malicious pickle data which will execute arbitrary code during unpickling (See https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/SECURITY.md#untrusted-models for more details). In a future release, the default value for `weights_only` will be flipped to `True`. This limits the functions that could be executed during unpickling. Arbitrary objects will no longer be allowed to be loaded via this mode unless they are explicitly allowlisted by the user via `torch.serialization.add_safe_globals`. We recommend you start setting `weights_only=True` for any use case where you don't have full control of the loaded file. Please open an issue on GitHub for any issues related to this experimental feature.
  model.load_state_dict(torch.load("model.h5"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mylab/Workspace/PyTorchScripts/helloworld.py", line 59, in <module>
    test()
  File "/home/mylab/Workspace/PyTorchScripts/helloworld.py", line 55, in test
    print(r2_score(y, y_pred))
  File "/home/mylab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_param_validation.py", line 216, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mylab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py", line 1281, in r2_score
    return _assemble_r2_explained_variance(
  File "/home/mylab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py", line 935, in _assemble_r2_explained_variance
    output_scores = xp.ones([n_outputs], device=device, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/mylab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_array_api.py", line 316, in wrapped_func
    _check_device_cpu(kwargs.pop("device", None))
  File "/home/mylab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_array_api.py", line 310, in _check_device_cpu
    raise ValueError(f"Unsupported device for NumPy: {device!r}")

According to the PyTorch website, my installation should cause PyTorch to run on my GPU, but SciKit-Learn seems to be referring to CPU.
How can I fix this?

Scikit-learn only processes numpy or pandas arrays, which are bound to the CPU and don't support GPU operations. So when you pass the PyTorch tensors to the r2_score() function, scikit-learn treats them like numpy arrays, which causes an error if they are still on the GPU.
You can still keep the PyTorch model and tensors on the GPU for model inference, but you'll just need to move them to the CPU with .cpu() and convert them to NumPy arrays with .numpy() for r2_score().
print(r2_score(y.cpu().numpy(), y_pred.cpu().numpy()))

